# How would I simplify a difference of a - b raised to the power 2m?

Tags: summation

I want to simplify something of the form

$$(a-b)^{2m}$$

in order to facilitate integration, so that it comes out of the form

$$\sum(a^{2m-p}(-b)^p)$$

Please note that 2m is deliberately even by the result I got.

Comment: Use the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: There should be some coefficients on each term in the sum.

Comment: I don't see how the second expression is a simplification of the first. Usually simplifying means to find an expression which is simpler than the one given. And simpler very often even usually means "using as little calculations as possible to evaluate the expression".

Comment: I meant to say put it in these terms that could be more easily amenable. But William gave a good idea I think.